# React Developer Tools Extension Chrome 40 Issues

Tags: google-chrome-extension, reactjs

have you had issues debugging React with the extension for Chrome since updating to Chrome version 40 ?
I can't inspect the props panel and cannot click with the mouse in the elements tree, I have to navigate with the keyboard.
I'll be glad to hear if they're working on it or if anyone experienced similar issues?
Thanks

Comment: Nope, not working on my end also

Comment: I had this problem a few times in Canary, and I used to reload the developer tools window to solve it, but it's disappeared now.

Comment: Fixed in the latest update version 40.0.2214.94